# Heroku dyno automatic restart - are the stopped functions preserved?

Tags: heroku

I have two web dynos in my heroku app, and at times get a dyno automatic restart (as per heroku policy). Is the function that was going on during the restart automatically restored in the new restarted dyno? If not, is there a way I can control this restart?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the function that was going on during the restart automatically restored in the new restarted dyno?

no

> If not, is there a way I can control this restart?

no

What you can do, is trap the `SIGTERM` signal that is sent to your process 10 seconds before it is `SIGKILL`ed. This would give you time to finish current computation, stop taking web requests, do cleanup, etc. More details on the process is in the [Heroku Devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown).

Comment: Thanks @Will , so I take it that there is some finite operational loss with each restart of heroku and there is nothing we can do about it?

Comment: There is something you can do, where you'll have 10 seconds to clean up. I'll edit my response to include that.